# When positive and negative rep changes add up to 0, I am unable to see the details on the rep list

Tags: bug, reputation, user-interface

When my answer was accepted on Math Stack Exchange, I got +15 rep.

The next day (18 June 2023), the OP changed the accepted answer, which gave me -15 rep.
The same day, I got +15 when some other answer was accepted.
In total, I got -15+15=0 on that day.

When I went to my rep tab, I could see the 0 rep.

[image: -15+15=0]

All okay until here.

Now, I can generally click that bar chart to get details on how I got those points, which answers were downvoted/upvoted/accepted/unaccepted/etc.

In this case, I cannot click, because these is no bar on the bar chart!

I agree that I should not be able to click on June 12 and June 16, where there were no rep changes. But I should be able to click somewhere on June 18 when there *were* rep changes, even though the net change is 0.

This is a bug in the UI.

Comment: You can still click on the button for the Time tab to see all reputation events in a list.

Comment: Which for your Math.SE account is https://math.stackexchange.com/users/464087/prem?tab=reputation&sort=time. The Post tab next to it also works (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/464087/prem?tab=reputation&sort=post).

Comment: I agree that I can see the Details via other "formats" , @Marijn , Hence the Bug is only in the "graph format" with Bar Charts. Alternatives DO Exist , but these are "work-arounds" to the UI Bug !

Comment: My thinking : We should have a Stacked Bar Chart : Positive Changes will be Displayed in Green , Negative Changes will be Displayed in Red , Total Change will be Displayed in Blue. When all 3 are Zero , nothing to click. When at least 1 is Non-Zero , we have something to click !

Comment: that would be a feature request though (i.e., added functionality), not a bug.

Comment: No , the UI Bug is there , the fix is to EITHER allow clicking Empty Bar Area OR Change the Bar Chart to Stacked Bar Chart OR Something Else , @Marijn , Hence I put it in Comment , not in Question !

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug. The feature is that if you click on a bar, you get a quick breakup. Without a bar, there is no element to click on in the UI. Anyway, it doesn't even matter if it's a feature request or bug report, just how important it is for the company to fix. And given that there are workarounds, probably not very important.

Comment: When I word that feature this way , it is a Bug , @NoDataDumpNoContribution , : [[ "When you want to get a quick breakup of a given Day , then click the Bar on that Day" : But there is no clickable Item ]] Consider these analogies : [[ "When you want to Power-off the Cell-Phone / Close the Web-Browser tab , then Press the Power-Button for 5 seconds / Click the X on that tab" : But there is no Power-Button / no X on the tab ]]

Comment: Your latest Edit to add the word "somewhere" is fine , @NoDataDumpNoContribution , though it has (strangely/inexplicably/curiously) made some user change 1 Upvote to 1 Downvote. I have no idea why !

Comment: @Prem I might have an idea, but typically these things aren't discussed in comments or anywhere else. They must remain a mystery forever. :)